# Angular js trigger blur event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to setup an input, such that when length == 5, it will automatically trigger a blur event. How can I do this?

This is pretty much the concept:

```
        <input type="tel" placeholder="type here." maxlength="5" name="digits" ng-model="digits" ng-change="if (digits.length ==5) { TRIGGER BLUR};">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic directive that should get you what you are looking for:

```
app.directive('lengthChecker', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.$watch(attributes.lengthChecker, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal.length >= 5) element[0].blur();
    });
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<input ng-model="digits" length-checker="digits"/>
```